# How to benchmark CUDA programs?

Tags: c++, cuda, nvidia

I was trying to benchmark my first CUDA application that adds two arrays first using the CPU and then using the GPU.

Here is the program.

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include<iostream>
#include<chrono>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

// add two arrays
void add(int n, float *x, float *y) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        y[i] += x[i];
    }
}

__global__ void addParallel(int n, float *x, float *y) {

    int i = threadIdx.x;

    if (i < n)
        y[i] += x[i];
}

void printElapseTime(std::chrono::microseconds elapsed_time) {
    cout << "completed in " << elapsed_time.count() << " microseconds" << endl;
}

int main() {

    // generate two arrays of million float values each
    cout << "Generating two lists of a million float values ... ";

    int n = 1 << 28;

    float *x, *y;

    cudaMallocManaged(&x, sizeof(float)*n);
    cudaMallocManaged(&y, sizeof(float)*n);

    // begin benchmark array generation
    auto begin = high_resolution_clock::now();

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        x[i] = 1.0f;
        y[i] = 2.0f;
    }

    // end benchmark array generation
    auto end = high_resolution_clock::now();

    auto elapsed_time = duration_cast<microseconds>(end - begin);

    printElapseTime(elapsed_time);

    // begin benchmark addition cpu
    begin = high_resolution_clock::now();

    cout << "Adding both arrays using CPU ... ";
    add(n, x, y);

    // end benchmark addition cpu
    end = high_resolution_clock::now();

    elapsed_time = duration_cast<microseconds>(end - begin);

    printElapseTime(elapsed_time);

    // begin benchmark addition gpu
    begin = high_resolution_clock::now();

    cout << "Adding both arrays using GPU ... ";
    addParallel << <1, 1024 >> > (n, x, y);

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    // end benchmark addition gpu
    end = high_resolution_clock::now();

    elapsed_time = duration_cast<microseconds>(end - begin);

    printElapseTime(elapsed_time);

    cudaFree(x);
    cudaFree(y);

    return 0;
}
```

Surprisingly though, the program is generating the following output.

```
Generating two lists of a million float values ... completed in 13343211 microseconds
Adding both arrays using CPU ... completed in 543994 microseconds
Adding both arrays using GPU ... completed in 3030147 microseconds
```

I wonder where exactly I am going wrong. Why is the GPU computation taking 6 times longer than the one that is running on the CPU.

For your reference, I'm running Windows 10 on Intel i7 8750H and Nvidia GTX 1060.

Comment: Copying stuff to/from the GPU takes time. If there's not enough work to be done to mitigate that overhead, then using the GPU may be slower..

Answer (score 1):

Note that your unified memory array contains 268 *million* floats, meaning you're transferring about 1 GB of data to the device when you invoke your kernel. Use a GPU profiler (nvprof, nvvp, or nsight) and you should see a HtoD transfer taking the bulk of your computation time.